# How to navigate between a specific group of posts in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a website for a school using wordpress. What is the best way to construct the classes and the students for each year? And what is a good way to display them and navigate between each year and show the classes for each year?

I tried showing them all on the same page. But i want to categorize each class with its specific year and navigate through each year.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Not clear enough :) I assume you are expecting to publish a page for each student.. then categorize with classes and years..

Answer (score 0):

I assume every student has it's dedicated profile page.
If you want to use the default Wordpress hierarchy,

- You can start by setting the pages dedicated for classes
- Then you can set the year number as a category (or tag) for each class
- Then for each student' page, you can set it's class page as a parent page. Using the page attributes [like here](https://wordpress.com/support/pages/page-options/)

Later you will list all categories links in the main page.

But if you expect a custom design, like a timeline or a tree or a big hirearchy chart, you need to use [page templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/) with custom [queries](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/).